# How to download a RPM package, and his dependencies as a normal user (not root)

Tags: rpm, yum

I can download a package and his dependencies using the following command:

```
yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/tmp/RPMs PACKAGE
```

But this command requires superuser privileges.

This is counterintuitive as I'm only downloading files, not installing anything.
But I guess the command check privileges before running the plugin.
Is there another command which would achieve the same result without the superuser privileges ?

The command `yum download` exists, but it doesn't fetch dependencies like the above command does, and I didn't find any option to do so in the man page.

For the context, I'm trying to install a package and his dependencies in a Docker image, which doesn't have the required certificates to download anything. So the idea is to download the packages from the machine building the Docker image, and copy them into the Docker image. But it's unthinkable to require superuser privileges to build the project...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the Unix & Linux stackexchange is more suited for this kind of questions.  Please next time ask there.

```
repotrack --arch=x86_64 --download_path=<path where you want to download the files>
```

For more information you can check the [man pages of repotrack](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/repotrack.1.html).

The package is part of `yum-utils`.

**Edit:**

> This is counterintuitive as I'm only downloading files, not installing
> anything. But I guess the command check privileges before running the
> plugin. Is there another command which would achieve the same result
> without the superuser privileges ?

The reason why you can't download the packages via

```
yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/tmp/RPMs PACKAGE
```

is that even that the operation itself is non-privileged operation you need to access the certificates that are protected against non-privileged access.

Comment: It seems repotrack downloads packages regardless of what is installed. It causes conflicts, even when the host and target are exactly the same OS. For example, I got conflicts between coreutils and coreutils-single by trying to install logrotate on ubi8-minimal, despite that I'm able to install logrotate using microdnf. On another test, repotrack downloads a different version of some dependency that was already installed.

Comment: @AdrienH Repotrack downloads the dependencies of the package hence the name. It does not take in account already installed packages. You would have to create a script for that which would match the downloaded packages vs. the ones you have installed on your system.

Comment: @AdrienH You could use  `repoquery --requires --resolve PACKAGE` and then use `curl` to download the packages.